# open window multiple times in loop

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, pyqt5, window

I hope someone can help me...

*The Goal:*
When the button "button_trog" is clicked it should start a loop that opens up a new window a specific amount of time based on the number chosen from the spinbox "spinbox_count" giving the possiblity to enter something.

*Situation:*
That works so far but the problem is that the window only opens up one time.

It should open up again when I click the accepted button.

I am not sure what to try next, because for my understanding it should open up the window again...
I mean the loop is working, I tried that with the print() function.

**This is the code from the main window file:**

CODE: spinbox_count

```
self.spinbox_count = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.spinbox_count.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 430, 70, 30))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(15)
    self.spinbox_count.setFont(font)
    self.spinbox_count.setObjectName("spinbox_count")
```

CODE: button_trog

```
self.button_trog = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.button_trog.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 390, 200, 100))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(15)
    self.button_trog.setFont(font)
    self.button_trog.setObjectName("button_trog")
    self.button_trog.clicked.connect(self.scanning)
```

CODE: def scanning

```
    def scanning(self):
    count = self.spinbox_count.value()
    self.lcount = 0

    if count < 1:
        print("Bitte geben Sie eine Stückzahl ein!")

    while self.lcount < count:
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = Ui_window_scanning()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        self.lcount = self.lcount + 1
```

**Here starts the code from the second file for the "pop up" dialog window.**

CODE: window dialog

```
class Ui_window_scanning(object):
def setupUi(self, window_scanning):
    window_scanning.setObjectName("window_scanning")
    window_scanning.resize(400, 300)
    window_scanning.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)

    # Label Description Scanning
    self.label_scanning = QtWidgets.QLabel(window_scanning)
    self.label_scanning.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 341, 71))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(15)
    self.label_scanning.setFont(font)
    self.label_scanning.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.label_scanning.setObjectName("label_scanning")

    # Input Barcode
    self.lineedit_scanning = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(window_scanning)
    self.lineedit_scanning.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 120, 200, 30))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.lineedit_scanning.setFont(font)
    self.lineedit_scanning.setObjectName("lineedit_scanning")

    # Button Accept and Cancel
    self.buttonbox_scanning = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(window_scanning)
    self.buttonbox_scanning.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 210, 156, 23))
    self.buttonbox_scanning.setStandardButtons(
        QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
    self.buttonbox_scanning.setObjectName("buttonbox_scanning")
    self.buttonbox_scanning.rejected.connect(window_scanning.reject)
    self.buttonbox_scanning.accepted.connect(window_scanning.accept)
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Please read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and check your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `self.window` attribute is overwritten everytime the while loops, and since the dialog has no other reference, it gets garbage collected (aka, deleted). You don't see only one window, you see the *last* window.

There are two similar solutions:

- add the windows to a *persistent* list, so that they cannot be deleted;
- set a parent to the windows;

If you need to keep track of the newly created windows (because you want to close them programmatically, or need to access their contents), a list is required anyway.

```
def scanning(self):
        # ...
        self.window = QtWidgets.QDialog(self)
```

Note, and this is **very** important: the modification above is based on the assumption that you're correctly using a subclass of QWidget (such as QMainWindow), and you're **not** using a modified file generated by the pyuic tool (or trying to mimic its behavior) and implementing `scanning` in any of its created classes (normally named `Ui_MainWindow` or similar and based on the simple python `object`).

If you're doing this (as I'm afraid to), consider that:

1. it won't work, as `self` is not a subclass of QWidget, which is required as a parent argument for any QWidget instance;
2. it's considered *bad practice* (there are lots of reasons for which it should never be done, one of which is confusion or problems with the object structure, like in this case);

In this case, read more about this topic on the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), generate again the code with pyuic and implement the logic of your program (with the above functions) as explained in that documentation - the multiple-inheritance approach is normally the better.
Please consider that any attempt to continue to use modified pyuic files due to laziness ("I've already written a lot of code!") or lack of understanding of the proper usage of Qt subclasses will only lead to a continously increasing amount of problems and issues that, at some point, will force you to switch to the common approach anyway - but at that point it will be much more painful and difficult.